# Что означает возвращаемый тип void?

Tags: php

```
void define(string $name, string $value, bool $case_sen = true);
```

Определяет новую константу с именем, переданным в `$name`  и значением `$value`.

Если необязательный параметр `$case_sen` равен `true`, то в дальнейшем в программе регистр букв константы учитывается, в противном случае — игнорируется (по умолчанию, как мы видим, регистр учитывается). Созданная константа не может быть уничтожена или переопределена.

Например:

```
define("pi", 3.14);
define("str", "Test string");
echo sin(pi / 4);
echo str;
```

Просим обратить внимание на кавычки, которыми должно быть обрамлено имя константы при её определении. А также на то, что нельзя дважды определять константу с одним и тем же именем — это породит ошибку во время выполнения программы.

Comment: Ещё один. Тоже до мельчайших подробностей?

Comment: сложно объяснить?

Comment: Объяснить __что__?

Comment: VOID используется тогда, когда нет необходимости что либо возвращать из функции и тогда, когда самой функции не нужно где либо сохранять результат. Посчитала - вывела, вызвала другие процедуры, функции.. По сути все.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как в других языках, но в пхп и в js если пишут void это значит функция ничего не возвращает. Там либо вообще нет return либо стоит return;

Comment: это  Котеров пишет